# Is 24 the Largest Integer where Squares of Coprimes are Congruent to 1?

Tags: number-theory

Let $M_b=\{a\bmod b:\gcd(a,b)=1\}$ be the set of all natural numbers $< b$ that are also coprime to $b$ (I have no idea if there's a general notation for this group, this is just what I use). Then I believe $3,4,6,8,12,24$ are all the numbers $b$ such that
$$
a^2\equiv1\bmod b \
$$
for every $a\in M_b$. Here's my try at showing why:

The subset of $M_b$ of numbers whose squares are congruent to $1$ must equal $M_b$ for $b$ to satisfy this, which means if $p^2<b$ for some prime $p$ then $p$ must divide $b$ for $b$ to satisfy. But the primorial grows way too quickly for $b$ to be able to contain $p\geq7$; it's pretty easy to see $30$ doesn't work, $60$ already contains $7^2$, and $210$ is greater than both $11^2$ *and* $13^2$. It doesn't work past $24$.

Does that work, or is this maybe not true? Higher even powers have the same thing too, though their sets expand of course thanks to the Fermat-Euler theorem.

Comment: $24=3\times 8$. Both the invertible integers modulo 3 and the ones modulo 8 form groups of exponent 2, so that every square is congruent to 1. They are indeed the largest ones (this can be done by considering prime powers only and then invoking the Chinese Remainder Theorem).

Comment: The question in the subject line should be included somewhere in the post...

Comment: Your proof sounds morally correct to me, though maybe it takes a bit more work to make rigorous.

Comment: Your list is missing $b=1$ and $b=2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (modular equivalence classes of) natural numbers that are relatively prime to $n$ are the "multiplicative units modulo $n$". Because given a natural number $a$, there exists a natural number $b$ such that $ab\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ if and only if $\gcd(a,n)=1$.

The multiplicative units modulo $n$ form a group of order $\varphi(n)$ (from which Euler's Theorem/Fermat's Little Theorem follows).

It is known that:

1. If $p$ is an odd prime, then the multiplicative units modulo $p^k$ form a cyclic group of order $p^{k-1}(p-1)$.
2. The multiplicative units modulo $4$ form a cyclic group of order $2$.
3. The multiplicative units modulo $2^k$ with $k\geq 3$ form a group that is isomorphic to $C_2\times C_{2^{k-2}}$, the product of a cyclic group of order $2$ and a cyclic group of order $2^{k-2}$.
4. If $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_r^{a_r}$ is a prime factorization of $n$, then by the Chinese Remainder Theorem the multiplicative group of units modulo $n$ is isomorphic to the product of the groups of multiplicative units modulo $p_i^{a_i}$, $i=1,\ldots,r$.

Saying that every square is congruent to $1$ is equivalent to saying that your group is of exponent $2$, or that it is a product of cyclic groups of order $2$. From the above, we see that if $n$ Is divisible by any prime greater than $3$, then this cannot happen (it will have a cyclic subgroup of order $p-1\gt 2$, hence elements whose squares are not congruent to $1$); it cannot be divisible by $3^2$ either, for the same reason; and it cannot be divisible by $2^k$ with $k\geq 4$ (because it will have a subgroup that is cyclic of order $4$, so an element whose square is not congruent to $1$ either). Thus, the only possibilities for $n$ which satisfy the property that $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ whenever $\gcd(x,n)=1$ are $n=1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $6$, $8$, $12$, and $24$. Indeed, $24$ is the largest one.

Your list is incomplete, though, as you see: you forgot $b=1$ and $b=2$.

---

Your argument is not very precise. "The primorial grows way too quickly for $b$ to be able to contain[sic] $p\geq 7$" is not a mathematically precise argument. What does "way too quickly" mean? This is at best a qualitative argument, when what you need is a precise quantitative argument.

In fact it is easier to argue that any number that is divisible by a prime greater than $3$ will necessarily fail (by using the Chinese Remainder Theorem to produce an integer that is $1$ modulo every other prime dividing $n$, but whose square is not $1$ modulo that particular prime), and similarly for $b$ divisible by $9$. Then the same argument gives that it cannot be divisible by $16$. Alternatively, you need to make a precise quantitative argument about the primorial, rather than the vibes-like argument of "grows way too quickly"...

Comment: Great, thanks! I will have to continue to digest this to understand, and reading my question again it does make me a bit embarassed to see how "vibes-like" I wrote it, but oh well, that's part of why I asked :)